# Dictionary Inception - How to print the example

Tags: python

Trying to access key value inside dictionary, inside, dictionary, inside dictionary.
This should print: "In Paris, France you visited Resturaunt 1, 5 times." How can I fix this?

```
travel_log = {
  "France": {
    "cities_visited": {
      "Paris": { 
        "resturaunt": "Resturaunt 1", 
        "total_visits": 5,
      }, 
      "Lille": {
        "resturaunt": "Resturaunt 2", 
        "total_visits": 2,
      },
      "Dijon": {
        "resturaunt": "Resturaunt 3", 
        "total_visits": 3,
      }
    },
  },
}

#Example Should print:
# In Paris, France you visited Resturaunt 1, 5 times.
for country in travel_log: 
  for city in travel_log[country]: # for Paris in France in Travel_log
    print(f"In {travel_log[country][city]}, {travel_log[country]} you visted {travel_log[country][city][resturaunt]}, {travel_log[country][city][total_visits]} times.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the following in your code:**

1. From:

   ```
   for city in travel_log[country]:  # This will give you ["cities_visited"]
   ```

   To:

   ```
   for city in travel_log[country]["cities_visited"]:  # This will give you ["Paris", "Lille", Dijon]
   ```

   - You are missing the `cities_visited` dictionary key. The flow should be:

     - travel_log -> country -> cities_visited -> city -> restaurant
     - travel_log -> country -> cities_visited -> city -> total_visits
2. From:

   ```
   print(f"In {travel_log[country][city]}, {travel_log[country]} you visited {travel_log[country][city][restaurant]}, {travel_log[country][city][total_visits]} times.")
   ```

   To:

   ```
   print(f"In {city}, {country} you visited {travel_log[country]['cities_visited'][city]['restaurant']}, {travel_log[country]['cities_visited'][city]['total_visits']} times.")
   ```

   - If you just want the country or city name, don't access `travel_log[country]` nor `travel_log[country]['cities_visited'][city]`, these statements translate to accessing the values of `travel_log['France']` and `travel_log['France']['cities_visited']['Paris']` which both would give you their dictionary values such as  `{"restaurant": "Restaurant 1", "total_visits": 5}`, but not the actual string value of country `"France"` and city `"Paris"`. Actually, your wanted value is already in the variables `country` and `city`.
   - When you tried `travel_log[country][city]['cities_visited'][restaurant]`, you are basically accessing a non-existent variable with name `restaurant`, when in fact, it is the string name of the key thus must be surrounded by quotes `'restaurant'` so the correct form is `travel_log[country][city]['cities_visited']['restaurant']`.

**Complete code:**

```
for country in travel_log: 
  for city in travel_log[country]["cities_visited"]: # for Paris in France in Travel_log
    print(f"In {city}, {country} you visted {travel_log[country]['cities_visited'][city]['restaurant']}, {travel_log[country]['cities_visited'][city]['total_visits']} times.")
```

**Output:**

```
In Paris, France you visted Restaurant 1, 5 times.
In Lille, France you visted Restaurant 2, 2 times.
In Dijon, France you visted Restaurant 3, 3 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this accomplishes the task of printing the statement for each city in dictionary:

```
travel_log = {
  "France": {
    "cities_visited": {
      "Paris": { 
        "resturaunt": "Resturaunt 1", 
        "total_visits": 5,
      }, 
      "Lille": {
        "resturaunt": "Resturaunt 2", 
        "total_visits": 2,
      },
      "Dijon": {
        "resturaunt": "Resturaunt 3", 
        "total_visits": 3,
      }
    },
  },
}


for country in travel_log:
  for city in travel_log[country]["cities_visited"]:
    restaurant = travel_log[country]["cities_visited"][city]["resturaunt"]
    total_visits = travel_log[country]["cities_visited"][city]["total_visits"]
    print("In {}, {} you visited {}, {} times".format(city,country,restaurant, total_visits))
```